# How can I draw a shape with GL_LINE_STRIP around a circle?

Tags: c++, opengl

I was wondering how I can draw a shape using poly-lines at different angles around a circle with immediate mode. So for example, like a frog made out of lines repeated at diffrent angles.

I have just got the basics of drawing a circle but I can't figure out how I would go about drawing the shape. The shape's vertecies will come from a txt file that I have been able to parse into (x,y) coordinates. But I am not sure how I would actually draw those verticies in a circular shape.

```
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glColor3f(0, 0,0);
           for(int i=0; i<360; i++){
            theta = (i*3.14)/180;
            glVertex2f(cos(theta), sin(theta));
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by drawing a frog in a circular shape. Frogs aren't circular.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Cartesian and Polar coordinates side by side. You were not adding the last line to complete the strip. Here is the function to calculate the coordinates.

```cpp
void drawCircle(const float cx, const float cy, const float r,
                const int num_segments) {
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++) {
        float theta = 2.0f * PI * float(ii) /
                      float(num_segments);  // get the current angle

        float x = r * cosf(theta);  // calculate the x component
        float y = r * sinf(theta);  // calculate the y component

        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy);  // output vertex
    }

    glVertex2f(r + cx, cy);  // output vertex

    glEnd();
}
```

Here is the complete code.

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

void drawCircle(const float cx, const float cy, const float r,
                const int num_segments) {
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++) {
        float theta = 2.0f * PI * float(ii) /
                      float(num_segments);  // get the current angle

        float x = r * cosf(theta);  // calculate the x component
        float y = r * sinf(theta);  // calculate the y component

        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy);  // output vertex
    }

    glVertex2f(r + cx, cy);  // output vertex

    glEnd();
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    drawCircle(0, 0, 0.5, 100);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Circle");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```